# Is there a way to read portions of a file in fortran?

Tags: fortran

I would like to read a portion of a data file based on what appears.
For instance, in the sample file below, I would like to read through the file and anytime there is "OW" on a line, the code has to go to the next line and store the three numbers there in an array.
How can I implement this?

```
amber                                                                           
         0         2        18
timestep       100        18         0         2    0.001000
   25.20       0.000       0.000    
   0.000       25.20       0.000    
   0.000       0.000       25.20    
OW               1   15.999400   -0.847600
 -8.3620E+00  1.0724E+01  7.9568E+00
HW               2    1.007900    0.423800
 -7.8947E+00  1.0963E+01  8.7573E+00
```

Comment: What kind of datastructure do you need to read it into? Do you have any code? You can read the file line by line into a string and then act according to the content of the string.

Comment: I want to read the first second and third numbers into arrays; x,y and z respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a sketch of what I proposed in my comment "You can read the file line by line into a string and then act according to the content of the string."

```
logical :: read_numbers
character(255) :: line

read_numbers = .false.

do

  read(unit,'(a)') line

  if (read_numbers) then
    read(line,*) array
    read_numbers = .false.
  end if

  read_numbers = (line(1:2)=='OW')

end do
```

It will set `read_numbers` to true when it encounters "OW". Then it will read the numbers in the next pass. Add any error handling as necessary.

Comment: This answer gave me some ideas on how I can implement it. Great!